# Problem for sending a word file having links with an excel file

Tags: excel, ms-word, hyperlink

I have linked a spreadsheet from excel to a word document (using special paste – paste link – Microsoft excel worksheet object). This works perfectly but unfortunately when I send both documents via email, the link is not working anymore and another laptop cannot benefit from the link.
I would like to know if there is an option to make the link remain in place even through email or a way to send those documents that would not break the link.
Thank you in advance,

Comment: See: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38722-word-fields-relative-paths-external-files.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.